# Paypal Donation button?

Tags: php, drupal, paypal, donations

I am looking for a way to display a button on my site for donations. If a user clicks it, they would be taken to a paypal page with all the necessary information on the donor's end already filled in. What is the best way to implement this in a PHP/Drupal environment? I already have a paypal account set up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://www.paypal.com/helpscr?cmd=_help&locale=en_US&countrycode=US&_dyncharset=UTF-8&t=solutionTab&ps=solutionPanels&solutionId=12013

> 1. Log in to your PayPal account.
> 2. Click Merchant Services.
> 3. Click Website Payments Standard, and then click a payment button.
> 4. Under Create Buttons, click Donate.
> 5. Complete the form (click More Resources for additional information).
> 6. If you want to add details, click Add More Options, and complete the fields.
> 7. Click Create Button Now.
> 8. Copy and paste the button code into your own web page code.
> 9. Click Done or Create Another Button.

Comment: Also: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_donation_buttons